# Python find Index of elements in List and remove in another List

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, indexing, range

I'm using Python 2.7 and couldn't find an answer to my question.

I have 3 lists (x and y coordinantes and the radius of detected circles):

```
XSum = [1316, 1324, 1330, 1344, 1356, 1344, 1356, 1308, 1322, 1310, 1336, 1934]
YSum = [960,  952,  972,  954,  964,  970,  948,  928,  940,  950,  984,  1080]
RSum = [379,  375,  355,  352,  340,  347,  338,  348,  361,  342,  342,  286]
```

I have to find elements in XSum which are not between 675 and 1350 (Index 4, 6 and 11). Elements with the index have to be removed from all three lists.

```
XSum = [1316, 1324, 1330, 1344, **1356**, 1344, **1356**, 1308, 1322, 1310, 1336, **1934**]
YSum = [960,  952,  972,  954, **964**,  970,  **948**,  928,  940,  950,  984,  **1080**]
RSum = [379,  375,  355,  352,  **340**,  347,  **338**,  348,  361,  342,  342,  **286**]
```

After first removal of index which are out of range:

```
XSum2 = [1316, 1324, 1330, 1344, 1344, 1308, 1322, 1310, 1336]
YSum2 = [960,  952,  972,  954,  970,  928,  940,  950,  984]
RSum2 = [379,  375,  355,  352,  347,  348,  361,  342,  342]
```

The next step is to find elements in YSum which are not between 940 and 980 and removed the detected index from all three lists (Index 9).

```
XSum2 = [1316, 1324, 1330, 1344, 1344, 1308, 1322, 1310, **1336**]
YSum2 = [960,  952,  972,  954,  970,  928,  940,  950,  **984**]
RSum2 = [379,  375,  355,  352,  347,  348,  361,  342,  **342**]
```

The resulting list should look like:

```
XSum_Result = [1316, 1324, 1330, 1344, 1344, 1308, 1322, 1310]
YSum_Result = [960,  952,  972,  954,  970,  928,  940,  950]
RSum_Result = [379,  375,  355,  352,  347,  348,  361,  342]
```

I think it should be an easy task, but I just couldn't figure it out how to remove by index from the other lists.

thank you all for the help

Comment: This is why it's generally better to make a single list of tuples or dictionaries, rather than having separate lists of each attribute.

Comment: You can do this type of filtering with a couple [list comprehensions](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/).

Comment: Umm... you know you're not dropping Y with a value of 928 there, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can group them together using `zip` and perform your logic to subset the candidates, then zip again (which inverses the original zip) and unpack into lists, eg:

```
x, y, r = (list(el) for el in zip(*((a, b, c) for a, b, c in zip(XSum, YSum, RSum) if 675 <= a <= 1350 and 940 <= b <= 980)))
```

Comment: This is good. You can even substitute the conditional expression with `range` itself, e.g. `if a in range(675, 1351) and b in range(940, 981)`

Comment: @pylang that's okay in Python 3 but on Python 2 it will build a list and run a slow O(N) containership test

Comment: Agreed.  On another note, compared to the expected results, `1308, 928, 348`  are missing from `x, y, r` respectively.

Comment: @pylang I think that's the OP's example output gone astray as 928 for Y doesn't meet the at least 940 criteria

Answer (score 1):

You should have post a piece or code to help us know how to help you.

Here is a very basic idea, assuming that all list are sorted to match each other (I mean in index order) :

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if a[i] == 2:
        b.pop(i)
        break
print(b)
```

It should print out

```
['a', 'b']
```

Now, you can imagine this mechanism nested into a class holding an array of arrays well managed by an insert and a pop out methods and it becomes as easy as abc.